# How separate grep result with comma in bash?

Tags: bash, grep, design-patterns

I have following grep command `echo $a | grep -Po '(?<=demo-jms2;)[^;]+'`. How I can separate the result of this command with comma?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

how about pipe the grep output to `tr '\n' ','`

Comment: It results in addition of extra comma! Use like `tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/.$//'`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `echo $a | grep -Po '(?<=demo-jms2;)[^;]+'`
do
    echo -n $i,
done
```